# Simulating and Testing Fargate Spot with ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Recently I've been looking in to Fargate Spot with ECS in more detail and trying to understand the capacity providers in ECS a little better. I'm struggling to understand some of the details and I'm struggling to test some scenarios.

I'm trying to understand what would happen if you have a capacity provider that looks like the below if Fargate Spot capacity is unavailable?

[image: Capacity Provider Screenshot]

I understand that it will launch 6 tasks using Fargate and then allocate additional tasks using Fargate Spot.

What if there is no Fargate Spot capacity available? What would happen?

From what I can see online, there is no failover between capacity providers. Is this correct?

Is there a way to simulate spot not being available?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a way to simulate spot unavailability. Also, there is no failback mechanism (by design) to on-demand. This is done on purpose because Spot isn't just a cheaper on-demand but more about capacity with specific behaviors tailored to specific type of workloads (those that can survive shortage of capacity for extended periods of time without impacting the outcome etc).